# Is it possible to save plus and minus signs inside a variable in python

Tags: python, math

This is just a general question as I am curious. When I run the following code I get a syntax error which is understandable. However would there be a way to save the + sign in an variable so I get an answer of 4?

```
SIGN = +
UNIT = 1
UNIT2 = 3
print(UNIT SIGN UNIT2)
```

Comment: You generally can't, as `+` is part of the language and not an object. You can however play around with strings and use a library like `sympy` to evaluate.

Comment: You can not store arithmetic operator in the variable, however as a workaround you may store the operator as string and achieve the desired result following the answers in the linked questions

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function for the `+` operator:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

and store it:

```
operation = add
unit = 1
unit2 = 3

print(operation(unit, unit2))
```

Functions for operators are even [built into Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html):

```
from operator import add
```

Comment: if it is a home-work exercise, one may also use `eval` here. For example: `eval('1 + 3')`